# Custom module for multiple store data

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created custom module in admin its working fine but I want to store module data in multiple store like product data where we can save product data in different languages like English, German and French.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you created your module, but if you want to shoose a scope for each view, you have to create a system config tab. then you can if you want create a menu like Cms, catalog, etc then you link this entrees to your sections. look [this](http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration/) Alan storm tuto